# Git, ignore folder except for some files with certain extension

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have a folder named **packages** in my git repo, I want to ignore everything inside that folder except for files with **targets** extension. I've tried this in my gitignore:

```
packages/
!packages/**/*.targets
```

but it doesn't work.

How do I ignore that folder but not the targets files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. I don't think it's possible using direct .gitignore rules.

However, this should help:

- .gitignore:

  ```
  packages/
  ```
- add patterns files:

  ```
  git add --force -- $(find packages/ -type f -iname '*.targets')
  ```

You *could* even make the add into a pre-commit hook to make this automatically pick up new targets files when they appear.

To properly support filenames with special characters:

```
find packages/ -type f -iname '*.targets' -exec git add --force -- {} +
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work for me (Git 1.8.2.1):

```
packages/**/*.*
!packages/**/*.targets
```

I needed the `*.*` part, otherwise `**` matches 0 directories, and a lone `*` at the end will match any directory inside packages, practically ignoring every directory, and any file inside.

I hope the `*.*` is not too bad for you, but having files without extension is pretty uncommon.

Comment: it seems to only ignore files with only one dot, so a lot of my files that contains more than one dot are not ignored, like: packages/AttributeRouting.3.5.6/AttributeRouting.3.5.6.nupkg

Comment: Strange. I created that exact directory and filename in my test repository, and it ignored correctly. The asterisk should match dots by itself, the only thing I forcing is having at least one dot, but two should be ignored. Which version of Git are you using? Which OS? (I am using Mac OS X 10.8.4)

Comment: It might be my version, I'm using 1.7.11 on Windows, I'm going to check in a newer version